# What is the cause of cannot get / error backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

when I run my backend files, I get the cannot get / error. I don't know what the source of the error is. As console output works normally, I tried it on localhost and tried it on different VDS's, but the result did not change. What should I do?

I don't know the source of the error so I couldn't try anything. But I tried to run it in different vds and got the same result again

Comment: Can you show us how you run your backend files ? What exactly do you mean by this ?

Comment: Could you share more info or code with us?

Comment: I start it by running `npm run dev` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the error means that the route/endpoint is not defined. For example you trying http://localhost/books and get "Cannot get" error means that there is no /books route defined in your nodejs / express app.

Comment: the link does not receive any links as you mentioned, the link is only localhost:3000

Comment: Same applies, then you have not routes defined for app.get('/',

Comment: so how can i fix this?